# How do I populate the destination of a report export based on the value of a text box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I currently have the following VBA code running:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "r_GRV_DETAIL_EXPORT", "MS-DOSText(*.txt)", "C:\Application\TSClient\Bin1\Scans\123.txt", False, ""
```

However, I will have different users using the application and they each have a specific location where they would need to export the report to (bin2, bin3 etc). I am going to have them select the user name and based on that the export location will be populated in a text book.

Question: How do I go about populating the above code with the location as defined in the text box (call it: txt_MAIN_SCAN_LOCATION).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you already have the path in that `txt_MAIN_SCAN_LOCATION` text box, or you also need to build it and send in the above text box? Do you only need to use the text box text in the above code line? What kink of text box is the one in discussion? A sheet text box? A form text box?

Comment: Yes, the path is already populated in the text box. It is a form text box

Comment: Then, use the next code: `DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "r_GRV_DETAIL_EXPORT", "MS-DOSText(*.txt)", myForm.txt_MAIN_SCAN_LOCATION.Text, False, ""`. Do not forget to change `myForm` with your form name. If the call is made from the form itself code you can use `Me.txt_MAIN_SCAN_LOCATION.Text`...

Comment: Thanks, your solution makes perfect sense. However, I am getting an "Object Required" error message when running the code. I suspect it might be something to do with the inverted commas and will go and play with. Any other ideas?

Comment: My form name is:

frm_MAIN_MENU

So my code looks as follows:

DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "r_GRV_DETAIL_EXPORT", "MS-DOSText(*.txt)", Form_frm_MAIN_MENU.txt_MAIN_SCAN_LOCATION.Text, False, ""

If I try that then I get the following error:

You can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus

Comment: 1. Do you use the above code in Excel, or in Access? 2. The text box in discussion is on the form? Does the code in discussion exist in the form code? Supposing that the text box stays on the form...

Comment: 1. Everything runs in Access
2. I am not sure what you mean with that. The form where the location sit is different to the form from where the code is running

Comment: I also tried

    frm_MAIN_MENU.focus

DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "r_GRV_DETAIL_EXPORT", "MS-DOSText(*.txt)", frm_MAIN_MENU.txt_MAIN_SCAN_LOCATION.Text, False, ""

Comment: For Access try, please using of: `Me!txt_MAIN_SCAN_LOCATION.Text`. Use `!` instead of dot `.`...

Comment: Thanks, trying it like this

DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "r_GRV_DETAIL_EXPORT", "MS-DOSText(*.txt)", frm_MAIN_MENU.Me!txt_MAIN_SCAN_LOCATION.Text, False, ""

Still getting this error:

"Object required"

Comment: I would suggest to create a variable `Dim strSpecif as String` and previously gives a value to it: `strSpecif = Forms![txt_MAIN_SCAN_LOCATION].Value`. Then try to use it in the initial line: `DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "r_GRV_DETAIL_EXPORT", "MS-DOSText(*.txt)", strSpecif , False, ""`.

Comment: I must confess that I didn't work in Access from a lot of years... If the above suggestion does not work, please try, also, this one: `strSpecif = Forms![frm_MAIN_MENU]![txt_MAIN_SCAN_LOCATION].Value`. If I also remember well, using `Value`, no need to previously set focus like in case of `Text` property.

Comment: And that sir, is a bingo! Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome! I was not sure I can help you, but, since nobody commented, I tried to remember. Initially I answered on the Excel VBA logic... So, I will put that in an answer, for somebody else having a similar problem. If you will tick the check box to the left side of the code answer, people will understand that this is accepted answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the next approach:

```
Dim strSpecif as String
strSpecif = Forms![frm_MAIN_MENU]![txt_MAIN_SCAN_LOCATION].Value
```

Then, use this new variable in your code:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "r_GRV_DETAIL_EXPORT", "MS-DOSText(*.txt)", strSpecif , False, ""
```

Using of the `Value` property will not make necessary the previous `SetFocus` on the text box, like in case of `Text` property.